# Update all subsequent entities based on specific criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a chat app. I want my users to be able to know if their message has been seen by others. For optimization sake, I want to do kind of batching for message update. That being said, I want to pass a certain message id, and then to update the **seen** field to **true** for all the subsequent messages. In this case I would like to update field **seen = true** for message id: 2, 3 and 4

Short question:
Have the input of messageId: 2
Output: all the messages with **seen** field = true

Having this inserts:

```
Messages.insertMany([
    { id: '1', message: 'Message 1', seen: true, updatedAt: 1231807011},
    { id: '2', message: 'Message 2', seen: false, updatedAt: 23098252526},
    { id: '3', message: 'Message 3', seen: false, updatedAt: 2390809345},
    { id: '4', message: 'Message 4', seen: false, updatedAt: 435623476375},
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in batch updates, one sends a list of ids to update, but in your case you can try this:

```
db.collection.update({
  $or: [
    {
      id: {
        $gte: "2"
      }
    },
    {
      seen: true
    }
  ]
},
{
  "$set": {
    "seen": "true"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TTNyW3LhFLR)